# Background fetch when app is terminated react-native Android

Tags: android, react-native, fetch-api, terminate, background-fetch

I have searched the internet for quite a while now, and I couldn't find anywhere a proper documentation to implement background fetch when app is terminated(not in background).

I have followed the documentation and implemented it like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    BackgroundFetch.configure(
      {
        forceAlarmManager: true,
        enableHeadless: true,
        stopOnTerminate: false,
        requiredNetworkType: BackgroundFetch.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY,
        startOnBoot: true,
      },
      async (taskId) => {
        console.log('[BackgroundFetch] taskId: ', taskId);

        PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
          bigText:
            'We will be watering your Plants in few minutes. Please check if your schedule is updated in Device',
          subText: 'Background task',
          title: 'Watering Plants',
          color: '#60ad5e',
          message: 'Expand to show more',
          actions: ['Okay'],
          group: 'group',
          date: new Date(Date.now() + 5 * 1000), //Change this to (scheduled time - some minutes) as to notify the user earlier.
        });

        BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
      },
    );
   
  }, []);


// And with with #scheduleTask
  BackgroundFetch.scheduleTask({
    taskId: 'com.foo.customtask',
    delay: 15000, // milliseconds
    forceAlarmManager: true,
    periodic: false,
  });
```

so here basically I want to run API fetch and show push notification to the user. So there is the chance that the user removes the app from background(i.e he TERMINATES).
So I want to show this Push Notification even when the app is terminated in ANDROID.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android, you have to use firebase to send push notification.
I highly recommend the @react-native-firebase app, and their documentation.

Basically, **AFTER YOU MADE THE INSTALLS**, the code is just

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';                                            
                                                                                                 
// Register background handler                                                                       
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {                                     
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);                                  
});                                                                                                  
                                                                                                 
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

In index.js

See their documentation for the firebase app
https://rnfirebase.io/

And the messaging part
https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage

Comment: Thank you I will check this out!

Comment: Accepting this answer because the only way to achieve this is using Remote Push Notification.